# How to automatically put a colorized underline under my glossary entries and acronyms?

Tags: color, glossaries, acronyms, underline

I want that all my glossary entries and acronyms are underline and that the underline are colorized.

I'm using this configuration so by default all hyperref links are hidden.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,backref=true,pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=false,breaklinks=true,urlcolor= rouge,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of glossary entries is done via `\glstextformat` so creating a `\renewcommand` will let us define a style for displayed entries.

Since acronyms are also glossary entries this will for for both of them.

For colourized underline some people will use the **soul** package with `\ul` and `\setulcolor` but I prefer to use the native `\underline` and a simple `\color`.

So first you set the color of the underline and then you are force to give the color of the text else it will use the same color as the underline.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,backref=true,pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=false,breaklinks=true,urlcolor= rouge,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,xindy]{glossaries}
% color glossary referencies
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\color{rouge}{\underline{\color{black} #1}}}
```